# bash eval command with two double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, eval

I'm trying to run a bash script that involves `eval` command.

Here is a small example to explain my problem in a simplistic way -

```
[root@localhost ~]# command="su - foo -c \"awk '{print \$1}' only_user_foo_can_run_it.sh\""
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# eval $command
bar and more words I do not want to show
[root@localhost ~]#
[root@localhost ~]# echo $command
su - foo -c "awk '{print $1}' only_user_foo_can_run_it.sh"
[root@localhost ~]#
```

In this example I want that the only output will be "bar".
I think it happens as a result of "deleting" '\' from the command and it refers to the '$' as a special character.

Any workaround to my situation?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: The general rule -- that if you think `eval` is the right answer, you're asking the wrong question -- applies. There's no good reason to use `eval` in the use case given. See both BashFAQ #50 (linked above) and also [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: Anyhow, `su - foo -c "awk '{print $1}' ...`, is buggy even without `eval`, because the `$1` is expanded according to double-quoted rules before the single-quoted rules are applied. (The double-quoted parsing happens before the `su`, the single-quoted parsing happens after it, so you have both).

Comment: Consider something like `inner_cmd() { only_user_foo_can_run.sh | awk '{print $1}'; }; su - foo -c "$(declare -f inner_cmd); inner_cmd"`

Comment: If you _really_ need `eval` for some reason not stated here, that may become something more like `inner_cmd() { only_user_foo_can_run.sh | awk '{print $1}'; }; outer_cmd() { su - foo -c "$(declare -f inner_cmd); inner_cmd"; }; command="$(declare -f inner_cmd outer_cmd); outer_cmd"`, after which `eval "$command"` should work -- but I can't conceive of a good reason to ever do that.

Comment: Hi, the reason I'm using eval is that I am sending commands as a parameter to a function that runs these commands. My example was just a dummy one.